Walmart Api V3 Search Item by Keyword
Hi i am trying to use the walmart marketplace service, specifically this endpoint:
https://marketplace.walmartapis.com/v3/items/catalog/search for a POST request (more detail in the Catalog Search documentation)
This are the headers i am sending:

Content-Type: application/json
WM_SEC.ACCESS_TOKEN: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
WM_QOS.CORRELATION_ID: XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
WM_SVC.NAME: Walmart Marketplace
Accept: application/json

Json body:
{
   "query": {
     "field": "productName",
     "value": "Iphone"
   }
 }

I have tried different body json with filters, sort and also i copied the request sample and the examples from the guide but nothing.
No query param seem necessary so i am not using any.
The error response:
{
    "error": [
        {
            "code": "CONTENT_NOT_FOUND.GMP_ITEM_QUERY_API",
            "field": "404_NOT_FOUND",
            "description": "No Items found for the input parameters.",
            "info": "Requested content could not be found.",
            "severity": "INFO",
            "category": "APPLICATION",
            "causes": [],
            "errorIdentifiers": {}
        }
    ]
}

I know it says there is no item but how is that possible, i used different keywords and for any appears something.
